# Bind9 nsupdate delete

Tags: bind9

The domain name has more than one address:

a.test.com:  10.10.10.10   a.test.com:  10.10.10.11

I use 'nsupdate' to add them,
but how can I update one of the records;

a test.com 10.10.10.10 ->10.10.10.12

I tried to use **delete the 10.10.10.10.in-add....** and it worked.
But when I delete the **a.test.com**, the other record is deleted too.
So when I nslookup a.test.com, None of the ip address can be found.

I want to know how can I just delete the specific record.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. You should instead delete all values and return needed ones.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I get the solutions:

```
nsupdate
>server 127.0.0.1
>update delete a.test.com 3600 IN A 10.10.10.10
>send
```

For reverse ip :

```
>update delete 10.10.10.10.in-addr.arpa 3600 IN PTR a.test.com
```